# Light emitted through a translucent plastic material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, procedural, photorealism

I often see hallway lights or street signs made from translucent plastic shapes inside of which is a light. The light doesn't spread through the thicker parts of the plastic, and some angles are materialized by being dimmer such as in these photos:

[image]

[image]

The darker areas help see the object's volume and its structure, and I am trying to reproduce the same thing in Blender.

I have tried to make a material that is a mix of translucent and transparent, and also transparent and volume absorption, but I cannot seem to get it right.

[image]

<sub>(Shared screenshot and version are shareable, dumbed-down versions of the current project).</sub>

Also, all the edges aren't outlined the same way, and it's hard to tweak their appearance.

Either the darker areas are too sharp, or the material looks like smoke more than plastic.

**How could I make this effect in Blender?**

[image]

Comment: Don't over complicate. Just use a simple *Translucent* shader, possibly mixed with a *Glossy* one if you want some reflections. Translucency will take care of the rest. Make sure your light emitting mesh is smaller than the translucent surface, to create interesting dark edges.

Comment: First, I seriously doubt that the bulbs inside the text sign are in the shape of the letters.  They are probably some kind of fluorescent bulb whether CFL's or standard T8 tubes.  I usually try to model as close to physically accurate as possible.  That said, the letters of that sign *have* a thickness.  So use a **Solidify** modifier and that will create the thickness in the corners that you're looking for.

Comment: I think [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/89440/935) has a solution for you.

Comment: Here's an interesting situation: the other question is indeed very similar, but the answers don't work in my case. [Both solutions make it look like this.](https://imgur.com/a/4zVBO). I'd like light on the background wall and the darker edges [like this](https://imgur.com/a/XfIfP), without exporting as EXF (because it's an animation).