# Shining light through model in Blender 2.79, Cycles

Tags: objects, light

How can I make this kind of light? 
Try to imagine plastic bottle of milk with light bulb inside of it, exact same thing (Like on picture) 
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89440/make-object-emit-light-be-reconizable and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24886/how-do-i-emit-light-from-inside-a-object/24888#24888

Answer (score 0):

Use principled shader. Go to TRANSMISSION set it to 1. Now it will look like crystal. Use roughness transmission to get it as you like. You can drive the effect using a mask or a texture with white vignetting effect on the sides and totally black on the middle so that light gets restrainted on the sides but passes clearly on the middle.